# How to read memory on the heap with Frida?

Tags: android, frida

I try to read a memory on the heap using Frida with a server located on Android Virtual Device (emulated) but all the time I got a memory `access violation` error.

First I'm looking for an instance of interesting class:

```
Java.performNow(function() {
    Java.choose("com.example.model.interestingObject", {
        onMatch: function(instance) {
            console.log(instance.toString());                   
        }, onComplete: function() {
        }
    });
});
```

As an output I get (I suppose) address in memory:
`com.example.model.interestingObject@d735e35`

But when I try to read from that address:
`Memory.readByteArray(ptr("0xd735e35"), 64);` then I get a following error:

```
Error: access violation accessing 0xd735e35
    at frida/runtime/core.js:282
    at /repl18.js:26
```

The question is, how can I read bytes from that address? I'm very fresh to Frida so probably do something wrong. Would be glad for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to cast the instance you found @ `onMatch`

`Java.cast(instance,Java.use("com.example.model.interestingObject")).toString()`

Everything else is good by the [docs](https://www.frida.re/docs/javascript-api/);

- `Java.choose(className, callbacks)`: enumerate live instances of the className class by scanning the Java heap, where callbacks is an object specifying:

  - onMatch: function (instance): called once for each live instance found with a ready-to-use instance just as if you would have called Java.cast() with a raw handle to this particular instance.
    This function may return the string stop to cancel the enumeration early.
  - onComplete: function (): called when all instances have been enumerated

To print class members you can use `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj.__proto__).join('\n\t')`

Comment: Running your solution I have the same result. Still have no idea how can I readp a heap memory...

Comment: please attach screenshots that will describe the issue and i'm sure i can solve it

Comment: There is a [screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/XL9Hzuk) of my code. I know that I could now read `obj` properties but since I have limited code visibility (I do RE on the app) then I hope I can find more data stored in memory.

Comment: if interestingObject class has implemented toString just use `console.log(obj)`, unless just print each member of it.. like normal toString

Comment: to print class members you can use `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj.__proto__).join('\n\t')`

Comment: Oh man! This is exactly what I was looking for. I wrote my own `getMethods()` [function](https://imgur.com/a/iYW2c0h) before but for some reason it didn't show me all properties. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the Java function `Object.toString()` you can see that the value `d735e35` is not an address but the hash code of the object:

```
public String toString() {
    return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
}
```

Therefore you are looking at the wrong memory address which results in the `access violation` you have observed.

In general for Java/Android you should never try to access the memory directly. Use the available functions of Frida instead to list all fields and their values.